# Why is systemd having trouble with a service PID file?

Tags: linux, systemd, nginx, yocto

I'm running a custom Yocto build of Linux on embedded hardware.  I have nginx installed, but it won't start correctly.

`systemctl start nginx.service` fails

When I try and start the service, it successfully creates the PID file, and nginx starts (I can connect via browser).  Everything is working.  And then it fails and nginx stops, and the PID file is removed.

I've verified that the PID in the PID file is correct (during the 10 seconds or so that it exists).

Here are the results of `journalctl --xe`:

```
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Mar 03 13:40:34 imx8mq-var-dart systemd[1]: nginx.service: Permission denied while opening PID file or unsafe symlink chain: /run/nginx/nginx.pid
Mar 03 13:42:04 imx8mq-var-dart systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 03 13:42:04 imx8mq-var-dart systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 03 13:42:04 imx8mq-var-dart systemd[1]: Failed to start Nginx Server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
```

`/lib/systemd/service/nginx.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx Server
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/nginx -s stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The permissions for the directories are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   13 root     root           340 Feb 27 14:42 /run
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           140 Mar  3 13:42 /run/nginx
```

These are the permissions for the PID file while it exists:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 Mar  3 13:59 /run/nginx/nginx.pid
```

/run is a tmpfs

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
```

Comment: Do you have selinux run?

Comment: Since it's explicitly complaining about the permissions or symlinks, perhaps you could show every level of `/run/nginx/nginx.pid` ?

Comment: Possibly related? https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8085

Comment: I'm not running selinux yet.

Comment: I added info about /run permissions, as well as how /run is mounted.

Comment: I do believe it is related to that PIDfile issue, but I don't see how I'm doing anything wrong.  I don't have any symlinks in play.

Answer (score 1):

remove installed service

```
systemctl disable nginx
```

And try replacing nginx service file with this template

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
# Nginx will fail to start if /run/nginx.pid already exists but has the wrong
# SELinux context. This might happen when running `nginx -t` from the cmdline.
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1268621
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```